# Text View c частотой обновления 1 сек

Tags: java, android, textview, android-textview

Начал программировать на Android недавно, помогите. На странице приложения есть **textView**, информацию на котором надо обновлять(показывать значение переменной) каждую секунду. В каком методе и как это надо делать? Можно ли делать в **onCreate()**?

Comment: А для чего обновлять ? Как ваш механизм подачи данных в textView работает ?

Comment: Откуда информация? Очень странное поведение, дайте больше информации о том как информация поступает и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Бесконечный таймер:

```
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    updateTextView();
}

private void updateTextView(){
    new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            /*Что-то сделали*/
            textView.setText("ЧТО-ТО");
            start();//Заново запустили таймер
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно запустить в отдельном потоке метод который будет получать данные для обновления и каждую секунду (в вашем случае) передавать в главный поток данные для обновления TextView. Запустить его можно и в onCreate, но тут важно отслеживать его привязку к активити! Вам нужно обрабатывать любые смены конфигурации экрана(например:  поворот экрана). Иначе может быть утечка памяти! Вам нужно копать в сторону работы с многопоточностью, AsyncTask-и, Loaders, Executors. Возможно RX Java но она для новичка сложна в понимании.